# fading images - argument error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to write a quick bit that loads some images into an array and then loops through them, loading and then fading each one out.  The error I am getting is..

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on images_fla::MainTimeline/goPlay(). Expected 0, got 1.

my code -

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay)

var images = new Array();

images[0] = "../1.jpg";
images[1] = "../2.jpg";
images[2] = "../3.jpg";
images[3] = "../4.jpg";
images[4] = "../5.jpg";
images[5] = "../6.jpg";
images[6] = "../7.jpg";
images[7] = "../8.jpg";
images[8] = "../9.jpg";
images[9] = "../10.jpg";

function goPlay() {
    for (var i:int = 0; i <10; i++) {
    loadWindow.source = images[i];
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(images[i], "x", Elastic.easeOut, 0, 300, 5, true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an argument in goPlay()'s declaration. Event listeners are invoked with an Event object that contains data about the event that has been fired.

It should look like this:

```
function goPlay(e:Event) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be tweening loadWindow, not images[i] ... and and the e:Event like Srayer said